# creating a layout for graph nodes with constraints

Tags: layout, igraph

I want to draw a graph. However, I have some constraints about the layout of nodes. namely, the y coordinate of each node is given in advance, and cannot be moved. I want to find suitable x coordinate for each node, so that there will be no/minimal crossing when drawing the (straight) edges of the graph. I know it will not be always possible, but my graphs are likely be rather sparse, so I believe that in practice this will be possible.

Any suggestion regarding how to approach this, hopefully with the igraph package which I use, but I'm flexible if you have other suggestions.

No example because this a rather generic question about generating layouts.

Comment: Are you plotting a layered network?

Comment: no. it is not necessarily layered, but the y axis should represent time, and each node has a given timestamp, so its location on the y axis is fixed by that. The network itself can be anything, really. rather sparse, so I believe there should be a solution for my needs.

Comment: If time is on one of your axes, then you probably have DAG? Then you could use the dot/neato layout (most prominently implemented in graphviz).